# SharePoint 2013 Web Parts by License Type

Tags: sharepoint-library

Is there a list of the usable webparts with standard / enterprise versions of sharepoint 2013 ?
For SharePoint 2010 we find http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-web-parts-by-license-type/
I'd like the same list for SharePoint 2013 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've used this helpful list a few times. It also tells you which features need to be enabled.

http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=214